# Create Button in datagrid row silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have the silverlight Datagrid like ,

[image]

I need to add one button in Every Row and If I click that button it will redirect to another page with particular row's **Name** Value.Because I need to show the Name value in the redirected Page.

Am new to Silverlight Application.Need your Guidance.

Comment: Dude there's a bunch of tutorials for this online, you're just looking to use DataGridTemplateColumn with a Button in it.

Answer (score 1):

Chris is right there are lots of tutorials online however for anyone who gets to this site here is an example.

Your datagrid would look something like this

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Padding="15" Height="129" x:Name="dgSOF" Width="1021" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestListBinding}" RowHeight="30" BorderBrush="#FFE4E4E4">
            <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Something}" Header="Something"/>
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Margin="5" Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Content="Click Me!"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        </sdk:DataGrid>
```

And then the code behind would look something like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ClickedSomething = ((TestSL.TT)(((System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter)(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as Button))).DataContext)).Something;

        SilverlightMessageBoxLibrary.CustomMessage cm = new SilverlightMessageBoxLibrary.CustomMessage("You clicked on " + ClickedSomething, SilverlightMessageBoxLibrary.CustomMessage.MessageType.Error);

        cm.Show();
    }
```

This should point you in the right direction